# Replacing str.length() with a variable storing it removes error although both are same and constant at all times

Tags: c++, string, recursion, c++14

```cpp
// recursive function
int helper(string s, int i) {
    int num = 0;
    int len = s.length();
    cout << "i" << i << endl;
    if (i == len) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (s[i] == '0') {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {

        if (len - i - j >= 0) {         // OPTION 1
        if (s.length() - i - j >= 0) {  // OPTION 2

            string str = s.substr(i, j);
            int n = stoi(str);
            if (n < 27) {
                cout << "call" << i << j << endl;
                num = num + helper(s, i + j); // recursion
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int numDecodings(string s) {
    if (s == "") {
        return 0;
    }
    return helper(s, 0);
}
```

In the code above, I have just used `len` in place of `s.length()`, as `len` is also storing `s.length()` and `s.length()` is constant and same in all recursive calls, as `s` is constant . Why does `OPTION 1` work, but `OPTION 2` gives me an error?

Comment: ...and what is the error?

Comment: They aren't the same at all because your variable is **signed** and `s.length()` is **unsigned**. This changes the way that the `if` expression is calculated. With `s.length()-i-j` you have an unsigned expression and all unsigned values are greater than or equal to zero. If you change the expression to `if (s.length() >= i + j)` it should work correctly.

Comment: You have to be very careful mixing signed and unsigned types in an expression, it can easily lead to counter intuitive results. In the code above you should probably change your `i`, `j`, and `len` variables to be `size_t` instead of `int` to avoid this. But even then you still need to write the `if` expression as `if (len >= i + j)`.

Comment: When dealing with containers use `std::size_t` for you sizes (and indices). 
Just make sure your calculcations will not result in negative values.
In any case, crank up your compiler warnings and do not ignore signed/unsigned warnings.

Comment: On a side note, if *"`s` is constant"*, it would be better to pass a `const std::string&` or `std::string_view`. Currently, every recursive call is copying the string.